# Ubuntu-phobic desktop refuses to recognize ubuntu install

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot, ubuntu-10.04, operating-systems

Question: Why does my computer not recognize ubuntu when I try to install it?

---

Info:

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to install on to my desktop. I'm duel booting it with windows XP for gaming purposes. I was told that when you dual boot with windows, install linux second because windows sucks at boot loaders. So I install XP and it's running just fine. I turn my computer off and install ubuntu. But when the computer comes back up, I'm not presented with the familiar boot loader that I've seen many a time on my other computers, no, instead it boots straight to XP with out a second thought as if Ubuntu was never installed.

I can get Ubuntu to boot through the LiveOS ability, so it doesn't seem like my computer is giving the OS a problem. So I tried installing Ubuntu first. Computer didn't even boot up. It just can't seem to find the OS. I tried making a new partition table on the drive that I install to, no difference. Still can't get Ubuntu to install.

---

System:

Time of this report: 7/5/2010, 11:37:08

```
   Machine name: DOTANUKI
   Operating System: Windows XP Professional (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3 (2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.080814-1236)
   System Manufacturer: My self, home brewed PC
   Mother Board: Asus P5Q-PRO
   BIOS: BIOS Date: 06/12/08 01:01:23 Ver: 08.00.14
   Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q6600  @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs)
   Memory: 3326MB RAM (though 6gbs is installed. I really want ubuntu 64bit so i can actually use all my ram)
   Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
```

I'm going to keep trying things, any pointers would be wonderful.

~n

Comment: What does it do if it 'doesn't even boot up', any error messages or seomthing?

Comment: If my memory severs me correctly it just says "Operating system failure" that's all. I'm about to attempt another install, just waiting on a burn. If/when the problem comes up again I'll be able to more accurately tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: When finalizing the Ubuntu install, on the last page there is an advanced button that allows you to choose where to install the boot loader. set it to the same HDD that your windows install is on. That should fix the problem.

---

Notes:

So it turns out I left out the most important detail. I have 4 hard drives. The boot loader was defaulting to sda, while i was installing the OS on sdd. hence my issues. when I told the boot loader that it was supposed to install on sdd instead of sda. all went well. I'm writing this from inside my fresh Ubuntu install, and I have successfully also rebooted into XP. So my computer works again now. I hate it when I figure the question out only hours after I ask the question. 3 weeks I've been missing that little advanced button.